# CMake Copy File to Current Working Directory Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake

I want to copy a shared library that is in my source directory to the program's running directory.

In linux we get there using `/proc/self/cwd/`

And I am looking in: `/proc/self/cwd/CMakeFiles`

> Compiled source files are located here, but I do not see my library.

What is the CMake command to do this?

I already tried:  `set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ./)`

Comment: c++ and c tags inappropriate, should probably remove that quote styling

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the manual section [Variables that Provide Information](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#id2). In particular, the variables [CMAKE_BINARY_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html) and [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) are useful as destination locations to your build tree. The variables [CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) and [CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) are useful for source locations.

Typically, when I am in my top-level project source directory, myproject containg the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file, I use a sibling folder `myproject-build`. For example

```
cd $HOME/myproject
mkdir ../myproject-build
cd ../myproject-build
cmake ../myproject
```

then

- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR=$HOME/myproject
- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=$HOME/myproject-build

Does this help?